# Google Calendar can´t get ColorId

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

Anyone know how to get the colorId from google calendar events? I search a lot on web for that and I didn´t find anything that works. I need help.

My code works good but regarding the colorId always receive NULL.

I know we have the **$cal->colors->get()** method but it's not quite what I want. I want the colors of each the events.

Here is my code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Ware");
$client->setDeveloperKey('CalendarKey');
$cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$params = array(
    'singleEvents' => true,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime'
);

$events = $cal->events->listEvents($calendarId, $params);
$calTimeZone = $events->timeZone;

$events = $cal->events->instances($calendarId, "eventId");

date_default_timezone_set($calTimeZone);

$jsonEvents = json_encode($events->getItems());
$outerArray = array();
$innerArray = array();

foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {

    $date = $event->start->date;
    if (!isset($date)) {
        $date = $event->start->dateTime;
    }

    $endDate = $event->end->dateTime;
    if (!isset($endDate)) {
        $endDate = $event->end->date;
    }

    $array = array(
      "title" => $event->summary,
      "description" => $event->description,
      "id" => $event->id,
      "location" => $event->location,
      "start" => $date,
      "end" => $endDate,
      "colorId" => $event->colorId
    );

    array_push($outerArray, $array);
}

echo json_encode($outerArray);
```

The **"colorId" => $event->colorId** is always NULL.

Public calendar is ON and I have the rights "Make changes and manage sharing".

How can fix that help?
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems like the intended behavior. See this [raised bug](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3684) (but tagged as Won't Fix) and this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/441).

Comment: Ok thanks. That is so stupid, but why!? I need that really bad I will see what can do.